# how to redirect and passing an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to post an array of data or a single variable string using the redirect() function in Codeigniter?

Comment: no... not with php/CI only: the parameter in redirect() is a string (route), where you want to redirect to. You could use clientside javascript and Ajax to send data.

Comment: Depending on the quality of the data, you might be able to pass modified data as a string which can be parsed and converted to an array by your receiving controller method.  (Some devs might not be in favor of this kind of hacky workaround, but it depends on willingness and despiration.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming you have an array.

CodeIgniter4

```
$array = [
   "a" => "aaaa",
   "b" => "bbbb",
];

return $this->response->redirect(route_to('YourRouteName') . "?" . http_build_query($array));
```

CodeIgniter3

```
$array = [
   "a" => "aaaa",
   "b" => "bbbb",
];

return redirect('your/route?' . http_build_query($array));
```